# Change back to previous state onClick button and texts

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

How do I change the text and button text back to its original state with an onClick? I know theres a setTimeout but I only want the change to revert back FOR BOTH the button and text when I click on it. Currently I can only use it one way. If i click on it, it changes from Original to new but I will like to change back to Original if i click on it again. Thanks!

Code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

 

const Card = () => {
  const[text, setText] =useState('original')
  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("Original");

  return (
    
      <div className='translate uppercase py-5 break-normal text-center mx-4 space-y-2 font-bold'>
        

        <div className="App">
            <button className='rounded-full border-black border-solid'
            type="submit"
            onClick={() => {
            setButtonText("New");
            setText('New')
            
        }}
        
      >
        
        {buttonText}
        
      </button>
    </div>
        <h2>{text}</h2>
        
      </div>
      
  )
}

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you Know both values you can use this solution

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
const Card = () => {
  const [captions, setCaptions] = useState([
    { buttonText: "orginal", text: "orginal" },
    { buttonText: "new", text: "new" }
  ]);
const[flag, setFlag] =useState(0)

  return (
    
      <div className='translate uppercase py-5 break-normal text-center mx-4 space-y-2 font-bold'>
        

        <div className="App">
            <button className='rounded-full border-black border-solid'
            type="submit"
            onClick={() => {
           setCaptions(captions);
            setFlag(flag === 0 ? 1 : 0);
            
        }}
        
      >
        {captions[flag].buttonText}
        </button>
      </div>
      <h2>{captions[flag].text}</h2>
        
      </div>
      
  )
}

export default Card;
```

If you don't know new value you can add to captions new value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const [isOriginal， setIsOriginal] = useState(true)

onClick={() => {
    if(isOriginal) {
        setButtonText("New");
        setText('New')
        setIsOriginal(false)
    } else if (!isOriginal) {
        setButtonText("Original");
        setText('original')
        setIsOriginal(true)
    }
}
```

By checking the original state, you can conditionally set text values.